# Unity3D: Spawn random objects one after another (2D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a terrain made out of randomly generated objects. I have created couple of prefabs and made a script that has all 3 prefabs in an array, and spawns them randomly. 
The problem that I have is that the objects (of different sizes) are being spawned in 1 unit distance, so basically over each other, instead of right after each other. 
The second problem is that I am not sure how to limit the spawning to a decent number. I have created a script that destroys the objects once I pass them, but in the code, at the moment, they are spawning infinitely, too fast (I know the code isn't the nicest, I am still practicing).
I did look for possible solutions or similar problems, but haven't found anything that can help me.
Here is the code from my script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SpawnScript : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject[] obj;
public Vector3 pos = new Vector3(-8,-4,0);
public float size = 1.0f;
private Vector3 dir = Vector3.right;

void Start () {
    Spawn();
}

void Spawn() {
    for (int i = 0; i<30; i++) 
    {
        Instantiate (obj [Random.Range (0, obj.Length)], pos, Quaternion.identity);
        pos += dir * size;
    }
    Invoke ("Spawn", 2);
}
}
```

I hope I can get any advises, references or help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are being spawned at 1 unit distance because you defined `size` as `1.0f`. Take the real size of the object instead:

```
GameObject go = obj[Random.Range(0, obj.Length)];
Vector3 size = go.renderer.bounds.size;
pos += new Vector3(dir.x * size.x, dir.y * size.y, dir.z * size.z); 
Instantiate(go, pos, Quaternion.identity);
```

See: [Find Size of GameObject](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/24012/find-size-of-gameobject.html)

Comment: Thank you, I was aware of the size definition, but didn't know how to get the object length. I have tried a similar approach, and always got an error that I don't have a renderer applied to the object.
With your suggestion, I get this error:
    `error CS0019: Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UnityEngine.Vector3' and 'UnityEngine.Vector3' `

Comment: Well `size` seems to be a vector. Does something like this work? `Vector3 size = go.renderer.bounds.size; pos += new Vector3(dir.x * size.x, dir.y * size.y, dir.z * size.z);` assuming that `dir` is normalized.

Comment: I get no errors now, but only one instance of an object is being spawned.. I will try looking more into it. Thanks again for giving me a lead
Edit:
All objects spawn, but at one same spot.. I think there is a problem with the prefab and getting it's size, for some reason.

Comment: You should read some basic tutorials... You will need to add a changing variable in the vector3 x and y positions so that your objects spawn at dir.x * x * size.x etc... X in this case could be a variable from a for loop...

Comment: The instantiation was at the wrong place, of course it has to be last of the shown statements.